# cordova android 6.1.0: "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds"

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have a cordova setup using the 6.4.0 version

i have several plugins saved at my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="~5.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-transport-security" spec="~0.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="~1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="~0.1.9" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0" />
<plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="~2.0.10" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" />
```

the platforms are ios@4.3.1 and android@6.1.0

when i run it on ios i got zero problems, however the android@6.1.0 gives me the following output when i use **chrome://inspect** to see why every xhr request i make gives me 404:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
```

if i downgrade the android version to 6.0.0 i lose icons and still does not work, only 5.2.2 gives me a working app.

any guidance is welcome, and i'll gladly add more info if prompted for anything specific.

Comment: Since you are using crosswalk, it feels this is a crosswalk configuration/use issue

Comment: @Eric looks like you are right! https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8984